# Parent bottom views hide with parent center layout view on opening keyboard

Tags: android

I am working on layout where I have aligned one `cardview` on the center of the screen and contact us `button` on bottom of the screen. This layout looks OK when keyboard is closed.

It looks like below :-[image]

layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/login_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/login_background" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/grey_background" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/media_card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/grey_background"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo_login"
                        />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/usertext"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/logoImageView"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                        android:hint="User ID"
                        android:maxLength="50"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/usertext"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/passtext"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                            android:hint="@string/password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:maxLength="50"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/hint_text_color"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/passwordeye"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/eye_close" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/termsLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/passwordLayout"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/check_box"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/checkbox_checked" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/terms_and_cond"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textColorLink="#80000000"
                            android:textSize="13sp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/lineView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/termsLayout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@color/grey_background" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/newuser_login_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@color/dark_grey"
                        android:layout_below="@id/lineView"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/newUserButton"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/translucent_round_button"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="New User ?"
                            android:textColor="@color/grey_text_color"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/bottom_round_button"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Login"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="17sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contactus_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/contact_us_selector"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/contact_us_green"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Contact Us"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textviewone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorLink="#80000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/snackbarCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

## Question :-

When keyboard opens then contact us `button` and text which is at the bottom of above screen hide behind the center layout. I want it should not be hide, on opening keyboard screen should be scroll and contact us `button` should be at the bottom.

On opening keyboard it looks like :-

[image]

Comment: you don;t have code on github or bitbucket to  play with it? :-) Just need this activity with all resources.

Answer (score 2):

Just a single line to be added...

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` in required activity of your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

in your scrollview add android:isScrollContainer="false" attribute

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your `CardView` is `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` , and your `LinearLayout` containing the "contact us" stuff is `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

I would rethink your layout, it's a bit messy, but maybe you can replace `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in the `LinearLayout` with `android:layout_below="@+id/media_card_view"`.

Comment: `android:layout_below="@+id/media_card_view"` is not working :(. still parent bottom layout is hiding

Answer (score 0):

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` should do the trick.

`"adjustResize" The activity's main window is always resized to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.`

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Answer (score 0):

Here's my layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/login_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/media_card_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/usertext"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/logoImageView"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                        android:hint="User ID"
                        android:maxLength="50"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                        android:textSize="16sp"/>


                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/passwordLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/usertext"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/passtext"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                            android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                            android:hint="Password"
                            android:inputType="textPassword"
                            android:maxLength="50"
                            android:padding="10dp"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                            android:textSize="16sp"/>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/passwordeye"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                            android:padding="8dp"
                            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"/>

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/termsLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/passwordLayout"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/check_box"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:src="@android:drawable/checkbox_on_background"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/terms_and_cond"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textColorLink="#80000000"
                            android:textSize="13sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/lineView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/termsLayout"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/newuser_login_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_below="@id/lineView"
                        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/newUserButton"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="New User ?"
                            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
                            android:textSize="17sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/loginbutton"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Login"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="17sp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/media_card_view"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_below="@+id/media_card_view">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/sym_contact_card"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="Contact Us"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textviewone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Copyright by piotrek1543 @2016"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorLink="#80000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/android:progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here's how it looks before opening the keyboard

[image]

and  after:

[image]

First of all, open your `AndroidManifest` and in your `LoginActivity` section put this line:

```
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
```

After that your `Activity` manifest should look like:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Then modify your LinearLayout with `textoneview` and `textview1` fields like this:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/media_card_view"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/media_card_view">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/sym_contact_card"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Contact Us"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textviewone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Copyright by piotrek1543 @2016"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorLink="#80000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Hope it will help

**EDIT**: If you would like to leave BottomSheetStyle of your linearLayout you can use this code:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/media_card_view"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/sym_contact_card"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:text="Contact Us"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textviewone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Copyright by piotrek1543 @2016"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorLink="#80000000"
                android:textSize="13sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

so it would looks like:

[image]

but after you open your keyboard you would see

[image]

Your "Contact us" would be hidden behind `CardView`. If you would like to have both `TextView`s think about decreasing size of `media_card_view`. For me it's too big to have both views visible.

Answer (score 0):

You just add few line in your code

Manifest File:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
```

If you have set background then problem with scrolling then set programatically background like below

```
   getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.app_bg) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this. I'm not sure it will help or not.

```
ScrollView view = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
view.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
view.setFocusable(true);
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        v.requestFocusFromTouch();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try putting `android:layout_below="@id/media_card_view"` in the LinearLayout that contains the Contact us Button and removing `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from it.

Also you can set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`  in the main RelativeLayout and maybe remove the CoordinatorLayout if it isn't used in that layout.

Hope it helps ;)